# Get another value from row with max value with group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry for the title. I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE people
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    FatherId int REFERENCES people(Id),
    MotherId int REFERENCES people(Id),
    age int NOT NULL
);
```

Which you can populate with these commands:

```
insert into people (name, age) VALUES ('Jonny', 50 )
insert into people (name, age) VALUES ('Angela', 48 )
insert into people (name, age) VALUES ('Donny', 55 )
insert into people (name, age) VALUES ('Amy', 55 )
insert into people (name, FatherId, MotherId, age) VALUES ('Marcus', 1, 2, 10)
insert into people (name, FatherId, MotherId, age) VALUES ('Beevis', 1, 2, 5)
insert into people (name, FatherId, MotherId, age) VALUES ('Stew', 3, 4, 24)
insert into people (name, FatherId, MotherId, age) VALUES ('Emily', 3, 4, 25)
```

### My Goal

I want to get the age *and* name of the oldest child of each set of parents.

Getting just the age was pretty simple:

```
SELECT MAX(age) FROM people WHERE FatherId IS NOT NULL GROUP BY FatherId
```

But what if I want to get the age *and* their corresponding name?

### I have tried

```
select p1.name, p1.age
FROM people p1
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT FatherId, MAX(age) age
FROM people
GROUP BY FatherId
) p2
ON p1.FatherId = p2.FatherId
```

but this just gives all the children because of the FatherId matching.

I can't seem to get the primary key (Id) because of the GROUP BY clause.

I suppose if this is not possible then some table restructuring may be required to make it possible?

### EDIT

Here is a solution I found using `CROSS APPLY`

```
select child.name, child.age
FROM people parents
CROSS APPLY
(
    select top 1 age, name
    from people child
    where child.FatherId = parents.Id
    ORDER BY age DESC
) child
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple tweak of your own attempt. One possible advantage of doing it this way it to allow for ties.

```
select p1.name, p1.age
from people p1 inner join
    (
        select FatherId, max(age) max_age
        from people
        group by FatherId
    ) p2
    on p2.FatherId = p1.FatherId and p2.max_age = p1.age;
```

Also you did refer to "set of parents" in the question. To do that you'd need to group by and join on `MotherId` as well, assuming of course that this matches up with the real world where children commonly have only a single parent in common.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that, yes the age must be the same. Choosing this for the simplest answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query and see this <kbd>**[demo](http://rextester.com/DOTS82010)**</kbd>

```
select 
name,age
from
(select p.*, rn=row_number() over(partition by p.fatherid,p.motherid order by age desc) from 
people p join
(select fatherid,motherid from people
where coalesce(fatherid,motherid) is not null
group by fatherid,motherid)t
on p.fatherid=t.fatherid and p.motherid=t.motherid
)t where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Two `nested sub-select` statements can be combined with `inner join` :

```
SELECT p1.age, p2.name
  FROM 
(
SELECT max(age) age
  FROM people 
 WHERE FatherId is not null
 GROUP BY FatherId ) p1
 INNER JOIN
(
SELECT age, name
  FROM people 
 WHERE FatherId is not null ) p2
 ON ( p1.age = p2.age );

age name
--- ------
10  Marcus
25  Emily
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/15147/10)

Answer (score 0):

This will pick up both parents

```
declare @t TABLE 
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    FatherId int,
    MotherId int,
    age int NOT NULL
);
insert into @t (name, age) VALUES 
('Jonny', 50 ),
('Angela', 48 ),
('Donny', 55 ),
('Amy', 55 );
insert into @t (name, FatherId, MotherId, age) VALUES 
('Marcus', 1, 2, 10),
('Beevis', 1, 2, 5),
('Stew', 3, 4, 24),
('Emily', 3, 4, 25);

select tt.name, tt.age
     , tt.fatherName, tt.fatherAge
     , tt.motherName, tt.motherAge
from (
select ta.*
     , tf.name as fatherName, tf.age as fatherAge 
     , tm.name as motherName, tm.age as motherAge
     , row_number() over (partition by ta.FatherID, ta.MotherID order by ta.age desc) as rn
from @t ta 
left join @t tf 
  on tf.id = ta.fatherID
left join @t tm 
  on tm.id = ta.motherID 
  ) as tt 
where FatherID is not null 
  and rn = 1
```